# Asp.Net MVC Partial view with Nullable<T> model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to develop a simple partial view:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@if (Model == null)
{
    <span>Active</span>
}
else
{
    <span>Resigned on @Model.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString()</span>                                    
}
```

and use it from another view:

```
@Html.Partial("ViewTemplates/UserStatus",user.ResignDate)
```

The view works perfectly unless it is a `Nullable<T>`.

I receive the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.UserModel]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'.

Of course user.ResignDate is a nullable date time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If model parameter passed to Partial method (user.ResignDate) is null, then asp.net-mvc passes caller view's model to Partial view, and you get error.

If you followed conventions ans placed UserStatus into DisplayTemplates folder, I would have reccommeded you to replace Partial call with [DisplayFor method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407420%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.user.ResignDate, "UserStatus")
```

Comment: Thanks archil but I don't have a model in the calling page (I am iterating on Model.Users and rendering user properties). Any ideas?

Comment: My code was just a guess :). You could do
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => user.ResignDate, "UserStatus")`, but as I mentioned, only if `UserStatus` view is placed in `DisplayTemplates` folder

Answer (score 0):

Please check data type of user.ResignDate
it should be DateTime not nullable DateTime